# Trouble including leaflet files

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="apps/mapeditor/Leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Locally everything works great. But when I put it online I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < [leaflet.js:1]
```

So I tried using the leaflet-src.js file but that came back with an error saying it could not get the file (online it didn't work, locally it worked).  Using the CDN works both locally and online, but I can't keep using CDN's long term.

I am not sure if this is even related to leaflet, but I can't find any info on this problem anywhere.

Comment: are you sure you have got the most up to date leaflet.js file?

Comment: @JoshStevens - Yes, 0.7.3

Comment: show your index.html (or something like).

Comment: if the cdn works why not save it locally and use that

Comment: @JonatasWalker - I'm not sure how anything else in my html file could be applicable to this?

Comment: @saj - How is that any different to downloading the file from leafletjs.com and including it the way I have?

Comment: It's up to you, but to debug it there's no code enough.

Comment: Moving the files out of the `dist` folder seems to have fixed it.  If anyone could explain any of this odd behavior it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Marty.H as you said it's working from the CDN perhaps a version diff

Comment: Was this resolved @Marty.H? I feel like some people were fumbling around in the dark here, without code.

Comment: I can't remember if I ever worked it out, I ended up cutting leaflet out of my project all together for a different reason.